# Use of single colon in C++

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

I saw the following code somewhere. But I don't know the use of the single colon in the line

```
auto& it : v
```

Does this mean pass the address `v` to each `it`? How the `for` loop access each address in `&v` ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int>& addOne(std::vector<int> &v) {
  for(auto& it : v) {
    it += 1;
  }
  return v;
}

int main() {
  
  std::vector<int> x = {12, -3, 6, 19};

  auto y = addOne(x);
  for (auto& it : y) {
    std::cout << it << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look up [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Comment: Will this help to understand https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for ?

Comment: it's basically a foreach: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-40-foreach-in-c-and-java/

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy Please don't link to geeksforgeeks. The web site is known for low quality, bad code style and many mistakes.